# Is _continue_ keyword computationally expensive in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, continue

I executed a profiling on my code when I realized a strange behavior. VS2013 is assigning a percentage of 6.5 per each of my continue keywords! Please consider the following snapshot.

Am I missing a point here?

[image]

**EDIT**
What if I replace `continue` with `if else-if` conditions? 
Well below is another profile. Can I assume the cost is vanished, or it's just spread-over ?!

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's really just the call to `MoveNext` in the iterator. In itself it's not expensive - it's just "skip to the end of the loop block, then continue with the next iteration".

Comment: Try replacing your `foreach` with `for` loop and see if you get the same number again for continue. *But you have to iterate your results first, either through `ToList`, `ToArray`*

Comment: Compared to `if` `continue` **is** more expensive. Or what is the question?

Comment: Change the code to use elseif instead and then see if it changes; as @JonSkeet said, the continue is probably just covering up the expense of the MoveNext call.

Comment: @AllanElder Can't change the first  if to else if and the other if to else if is not going to change the actual execution of the code.

Comment: @blam he can change the 2nd two if statements to be else if and remove the two continues. This way, the code is functionally the same (granted, tho more ContainsKey checks) but it will show up in the profiler.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, lose the `ContainsKey` checks.  For example, [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells you whether the key was found and removed.  Looking up the item twice is wasteful.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right, I can do it for 2nd `if`, but I guess it wouldn't be possible for 3rd `if`.

Comment: @Hamed: It is, if you (1) replace `Add` with subscript, which will succeed whether or not the key already exists.  (2) stop decrementing the `rightEndsToFind` variable -- you don't need to keep track of the number of elements added since the collection already does (3) change the early escape condition to `if (rightEndsToFind == determinedLambdas.Count)`.  Well, I suppose this isn't quite the same because it will select the last item matching each key instead of the first.  Is that important?

Comment: It's too bad that `TryAdd` doesn't exist in a normal dictionary.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess your proposal, although great, but break the logic of algorithm, e.g., `_rightEndsToFind` is unavoidable for this algorithm.

Comment: @Hamed: Why?  Isn't there an invariant that `_rightEndsToFind` is always equal to `initial_value - determinedLambdas.Count` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm afraid not, because this variable is set by different functions based on various logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; `continue` is typically mapped to an unconditional branch (`br` or `br.s`). The only "expense" here is *what happens next* - in your case, a `MoveNext()`. What *that* does is entirely specific to your sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I think I would better spend some time on iteration too :) that seems to encapsulated the cost specified for `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on making it more efficient
In real life more efficient is going to run faster

Borrowing from comments
I might be faster to let it throw an exception on the add
And it might NOT be faster to let it throw an exception on the add

```
foreach (var lamda in ...
{
     if (lamda.phi == true)
     {
         ...
     }
     else if (_left.Remove(lamda.Ati))
     {}
     else 
     {
        try 
        {
            _determined.Add(lamda.Ati, lamda.phi)
            _righEnds --; 
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            // do nothing
        }   
     }
}
```

On the _determined.Add lamda.phi is always going to be false
Why not a HashSet?
HashSet.Add returns a bool

Comment: Thanks, I like avoiding 2nd `if` since it consumes ~10% but still I'm not convinced for 3rd `if` replacement. I wish there would be something like `.TryAdd` as in `ConcurrentCollections`

Comment: HashSet is a much better option here than exceptions.

Comment: Time to start testing with actual data.  Those profile % are to find hot spots.   8% is not necessarily faster then 10% with you data.  8% might not be faster than 20%.

Comment: @BenVoigt But HashSet is not an option if there are some values of true in that dictionary.   OP came back with would like a TryAdd for Dictionary.